# Maven + Spring + Apache CXF : java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource

Tags: spring, maven, cxf

I am trying to run this tutorial: http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-example-reportincident-part1.html

I am having troubles with Spring and CXF and got this error when launching 
mvn jetty:run

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/C:/Users/Mokhtar/Desktop/maven]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/C:/Users/Mokhtar/Desktop/maven]

Those are the dependecies I've added to the POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Don't understand why it doesn't work